# Mysql Data structure

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm currently making a system where i have to save 2 forms and a file upload.

1. Users will be able to give their info (name,lastname,street, address, ...). Once that's done i save this info in a table and proceed to the next form.
2. Second form is about info on a topic they want to subscribe. For example they fill in the info of their kid,dog,car. Doesn't really matter.  Once the second form has been submit i also save it inside the database.
3. Upload a picture and save the random filename on the dog for example.

The main question now is that i need some status object for the 1st database entry.

The user can fill in he's info and subscribe a dog (2nd form info and 3de form picture).

If the user didn't fill in he's 2nd form i want to send a reminder email saying that he didn't but for that i'll need a CHRON job (php) and a status of the user ofcourse.

My main concern is that a user should be able to upload multiple dogs and still recieve the appropriate email. If i keep the status with the user than what happens when 2 dogs are uploaded. They end up in a different tables with a foreign key to the user.

I Could also store the status of the dog within the dog table. But than i'm having the problem that if the user fills in he's form but doesn't provide info for a dog i won't have an entry in the dog table and no status on the dog.

Would you guys have any thought on how to make the datastructure easier to keep a status on a user and dog all in one table ? For example when a user makes a dog i already make an empty entry for a dog ? Or isn't that a good solution ?

Attachment print screen of Datastructure[image]

[image]

Short summary (1. Participant fills out form -> save -> 2.Participant fills in info about he's topic (dog,cat,kid,whatever the thing is about) -> save -> 3. upload picture -> save)

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Hey Siebe.V, you can make a mapping table(id, topicId, participantId, status). if user has not entered any info of form2 that mean we will not get any entry in mapping table so you can easily find , which user did not put info in form 2  and can trigger mail.    I have a questions.. 1. what exactly you want to save in participant_status and in topic_status?

Comment: That's why i made those tables. When the user filled in form1 i was going to save he's status 1 to participant_status. That way i would know he entered that info. Once he entered the topic (kid,dog,whatever) the participant would change back to status 0 (so he can later on upload more topics. and i would from then on give the status to the topic. topic_status 1 for form2 completed and topic_status 2 if the participant uploaded a picture for that topic.

Comment: That's why everything sounds so messed up right now. Cause i basicly have to give the status from the participant on to the topic which sounds like there should be a different option. Your mapping table could be a fix. I'll see what i will work out. If you have any other idea's i'm glad to recieve them !

Comment: I solved my problem and made a new scheme.Thanks for your input @meetisharma

Comment: You’re Welcome @Siebe. V

Comment: "Over-normalization" -- get rid of the tables down the middle.